# swfupload + paperclip + rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i easily entegrate swfupload to my application?

```
<%= form_for(@photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.file_field :attachment %>
<%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Photo model

```
has_attached_file :attachment, 
                  :styles => { :small => "200x100", :big => "500x300>" }, 
                  :url  => "/images/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
              :path => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/public/images/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

photos controller

```
  def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])
      if @photo.save
        redirect_to(@photo)
      else
        render :action => "new"
      end
  end
```

Comment: Question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900769/using-rails-with-paperclip-and-swfupload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two apps here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax

- with jQuery upload
- with swfupload

They could be good examples

Comment: You don't use swfupload in this application anymore, correct?

Comment: There was a dedicated branch, but it's no more in master